# Compatibility between Protobuf and Protostuff

Tags: java, compatibility, protocol-buffers, protostuff

are Classes generated by the Protostuff code generator compatible with those created by Protobuf?

I tried to (de)serialize some simple messages and got several exceptions:

**Proto-File (WrapperClass.proto)**

```
package tutorial;
option java_package = "com.example.tutorial";
message ProjectId {
    required int32 id = 1;
}
message UserId {
    required ProjectId project = 1;
    required int32 projectUserId = 2;
}
message ChannelId {
    required ProjectId project = 1;
    required string name = 2;
}
```

**Protostuff to Protobuf Test (example)**

```
ProjectId projectId = new ProjectId(1);
byte[] projectarray = ProtostuffIOUtil.toByteArray(projectId, ProjectId.getSchema(), buffer);
com.example.tutorial.WrapperClass.ProjectId returnBufProject = com.example.tutorial.WrapperClass.ProjectId.parseFrom(projectarray);
```

**Problem:**

Everything works for ProjectId, but for UserId and ChannelId (everything a little bit more complex), i get:

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Message missing required fields: project
    at com.google.protobuf.UninitializedMessageException.asInvalidProtocolBufferException(UninitializedMessageException.java:81)
    at com.example.tutorial.WrapperClass$ChannelId$Builder.buildParsed(Test.java:1278)
    at com.example.tutorial.WrapperClass$ChannelId$Builder.access$17(Test.java:1273)
    at com.example.tutorial.WrapperClass$ChannelId.parseFrom(Test.java:1142)
    ...
```

And the other way around:

**Protobuf to Protostuff Test (example)**

```
com.example.tutorial.WrapperClass.ProjectId projectId2 = com.example.tutorial.WrapperClass.ProjectId.newBuilder().setId(1).build();
byte[] project2array = projectId2.toByteArray();
ProjectId returnStufProject = new ProjectId();
ProtostuffIOUtil.mergeFrom(project2array, returnStufProject, ProjectId.getSchema());
```

**Problem**

again, for everything other than the ProjectId, there is an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Reading from a byte array threw an IOException (should never happen).
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.IOUtil.mergeFrom(IOUtil.java:53)
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.ProtostuffIOUtil.mergeFrom(ProtostuffIOUtil.java:96)
    at JacksonTest.main(JacksonTest.java:92)
Caused by: com.dyuproject.protostuff.ProtobufException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.ProtobufException.invalidTag(ProtobufException.java:98)
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.ByteArrayInput.readFieldNumber(ByteArrayInput.java:220)
    at com.example.tutorial.ProjectId$1.mergeFrom(ProjectId.java:115)
    at com.example.tutorial.ProjectId$1.mergeFrom(ProjectId.java:1)
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.ByteArrayInput.mergeObjectEncodedAsGroup(ByteArrayInput.java:390)
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.ByteArrayInput.mergeObject(ByteArrayInput.java:362)
    at com.example.tutorial.UserId$1.mergeFrom(UserId.java:138)
    at com.example.tutorial.UserId$1.mergeFrom(UserId.java:1)
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.IOUtil.mergeFrom(IOUtil.java:43)
    ... 2 more
```

Am i trying something impossible or do i only do something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was simple:
Instead of using `ProtostuffIOUtil` to (de)serialize my messages i need to use `ProtobufIOUtil`

Comment: I just encountered a similar exception in a similar situation. In my case the problem with that I was passing ProtobufIOUtil.mergeFrom() a byte array with an incorrect length specified.